# How do I create content programatically?

Tags: 7, nodes

In WordPress I can use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create content programatically.

Is there any similar function available for Drupal 7, that will allow me to insert posts (and pages) into the database programatically?

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I changed the wording of the question a bit to make it potentially more useful and easier to find for others coming from a wordpress background

Answer (score 2):

you can create a custom function to create a node.

```
function create_my_node() {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'your content type';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title = "your title";
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  global $user;

  $newnode->uid = $user->uid;
  $newnode->name = $user->name;
  $newnode->status = 1;     // 1 means published
  $newnode->promote = 0;
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that,, pls give me some reference if possible..

Comment: [Here you go](http://drupal.org/node/1388922).